# XML Parsing Cobol

Tags: xml-parsing, cobol

I have written a COBOL module for parsing a XML. XML value is stored in a DB2 table and I am running a select query to read the XML value. But while parsing, on the 1st instance itself it is throwing an exception with XML-CODE = 317. I did a search on this XML Code and found the description of this error as follows - 'The parser cannot determine the document encoding. The document may be damaged.'

There is no issue with the XML otherwise it would have thrown error while inserting into DB2 table. 1st tag in XML is  which is also correct.

Can somebody please help me out in resolving this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I tend to go with what the computer says. A computer is unable to hoodwink itself by "thinking" for itself that it knows something which is not supported by th evidence. If you have correctly identified the message, then I believe what the computer says rather than what you think. Concentrate on finding out how the parser determines the document encoding.

Comment: Can you please help me out on how should i find how the parser is determining the document encoding. Before the XML is being uploaded Encoding was UTF-8 and after XML is inserted it is written Encoding is IBM01146. Also I checked that the table is a UNICODE table.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have to specify an encoding on your XML header.

Here are some example encodings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Comment: XML Header is already present as <?xml version="1.0" encoding="IBM01146"?>

Answer (score 1):

You have given us some useful information...

1. You are attempting to parse XML in COBOL
2. The XML comes from another machine
3. The XML is originally UTF-8
4. The XML is stored in a DB2 table in a Unicode column
5. The XML has a header indicating it is [code page 1146](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_285)
6. You are receiving an XML-CODE of 317

What [CODEPAGE](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ui/up6080.htm) option was your COBOL code compiled with?  There may be an automatic conversion taking place, perhaps the header and the encoding no longer match after retrieval from DB2.

Are you parsing a PIC X field or a PIC N field?

Also, I suggest using the compile option [XMLPARSE(XMLSS)](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/pdthelp/v1r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ui/up7200.htm) as the "native COBOL" parser is deprecated as of Enterprise COBOL 5.1.